# what is the default text color code in night theme?

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-edittext, textcolor

I didn't change text color for the rest of my code but one edit-text. so the text color of the rest of the code is automatically changed when night theme switches but that one I changed manually doesn't.

I want to give my edit-text the same color so that it doesn't look different from the rest of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Define the colors you want `day` and `night` in the `colors.xml` The colors you have for both themes and will be used for those colors you specify.
place each of those colors in the respected themes. example:

`day`

```
<style name="Theme.Shindig" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

`night`

```
<style name="Theme.Shindig" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">#F8F5F5</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

`**Note I did not label the exact colors, so in` dark theme `the Primary color is light black, i did not change the purple color to reflect light black. However this is an example. the color you place will be the color name in the colors.xml**`

These are different color schemes for each them respectively. These will be different colors based on the theme. So for example when you call the `night theme` you set colors will be visible and different from the `day theme`. Now with `night theme` you want to have light colors. So when you call either theme  the colors will be chosen as they were set.

The `text` uses the `colorOnSecondary` portion as I have here.

To manually switch to Day?Dark mode go into the settings of the phone and turn on dark mode on the phone and then go back to the app and you will see the difference. If you have a toggle you can switch between the themes by the toggle.

Once you have chosen the colors it will look like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> themas.xml(night)

```
<style name="TextColor">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

> themas.xml

```
<style name="TextColor">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        </style>
```

> layout.xml

```
<TextView
...
style="@style/SortTablayout"
/>
```

> or

```
<style name="Theme.YourThema" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="textFillColor">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item> <!--<- -->
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```